# Drop down list value is null when changed in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hi i have this DDL in my html code as you can see :

```
<select class="form-control" name="RoleId" id="RoleId">
                                                <option value="1">User</option>
                                                <option value="2">Admin</option>
                                                <option value="3">Security</option>

                                        </select>
```

I call my json action contoller with this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#RoleId").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRolePolicy", "RolePolicy", new { area= "Admin" })',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { RoleName: $("#RoleId").val() },
                success: function (data) {


                    var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
```

I need the value of selected item in combobox but this line of code

{ RoleName: $("#RoleId").val() },

Return null to my action in controller .why ?

```
                    public JsonResult GetRolePolicy(string RoleId)
        {
            int RoleIdConverted = int.Parse(RoleId);
            RolePolicy _RolePolocy = new RolePolicy();
}
```

Comment: show code of your controller

Comment: Seems to be getting the value just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/307919/  How have you confirmed that the problem is in your HTML and/or JavaScript and not somewhere else?

Comment: can you share name of your controller's params ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a parameter called `RoleName`:

```
data: { RoleName: $("#RoleId").val() }
```

But expecting a parameter called `RoleId`:

```
public JsonResult GetRolePolicy(string RoleId)
```

The parameter names need to match.  Rename one of them.

Answer (score 1):

your action param name should be `RoleName`

```
public JsonResult GetRolePolicy(string RoleName)
```